# Seeking uplifting vort for Thanksgiving day table

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mussar-ethics, thanksgiving

I am looking for suggestions for one or more short discussion topics or teachings for the Thanksgiving day table, with kids from 10 years of age and up.  Topics alone are fine, but topics fleshed out would be even better.  I am looking for topics that may catch the interest of those who are not halachically sophisticated.   So, the kashrut of Turkey or the bracha over stuffing are not the type of topic I am looking for. Perhaps facets of the Jewish view of charity or prosperity or parallels to Jewish harvest festivals.

Supplement
In addition to the fine contribution by @danno, a little web search on vort and thanksgiving turned up these pages:
http://ahavasisrael.org/torah/the_short_vort/the_short_vort_a_thanksgiving_special_11_24_10/
http://www.aish.com/sp/pg/48900507.html?s=rab
http://www.aish.com/sp/pg/48923947.html?s=rab
http://www.aish.com/sp/pg/8-Ways-to-be-More-Thankful.html?s=fab

 More are welcome.

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but today I have been thinking about Rav Hutner's explanation of the dual meaning of "modim" -- http://www.torahweb.org/torah/2006/parsha/rsac_vaera.html

Comment: it would be ironic to say over a vort from Rav Hutner at a thanksgiving dinner since he prohibited a thanksgiving dinner.

Comment: @sam  Ironic has a wide range of meanings, from absurd to illogical.  I would not rule out discussing a thinker or teacher for the reason you raise.

Comment: Meant it as more of joke,of course you should say it

Comment: @sam  Oh. OK.  (I am somewha humor challenged.)

Comment: Lol ,np will keep that in mind